# constant parameters sfactor and dfactor of blendfunc

Tags: webgl

why in the parameters of the blendFunc(sfactor, dfactor), the following particular case is not possible ?

**If a constant color and a constant alpha value are used together as source and destination factors,   *a gl.INVALID_ENUM error is thrown.**

I wanted to do this particular case:

gl.blendColor(0.2,0.5,0.7,0.8);
gl.blendFunc(gl.CONSTANT_ALPHA, gl.CONSTANT_COLOR);
// color(RGBA ) = (sourceColor  * CONSTANT_ALPHA) + (destination* CONSTANT_COLOR)

i think that means :
color(RGBA) = sourceColor * (0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8) + destination * (0.2,0.5,0.7,0.8)

but then if this formula is correct, why does it generate an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does it generate an error message

The "easy" answer is that "the spec requires it." Section 6.15 of the WebGL 1.0 spec says:

> In the WebGL API, constant color and constant alpha cannot be used together as source and destination factors in the blend function. A call to blendFunc will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error if one of the two factors is set to CONSTANT_COLOR or ONE_MINUS_CONSTANT_COLOR and the other to CONSTANT_ALPHA or ONE_MINUS_CONSTANT_ALPHA.

So, even though you could mathematically define what would happen for this combination of blend factors, WebGL forbids it from being used. Now as to *why* that's the case... This github issue (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/2938) explains that it's due to a difference between Direct3D and OpenGL: D3D doesn't allow constant alpha (only constant color), so ANGLE simulates the constant alpha by using a color of (a,a,a,a). But if you are using the color slots to hold the alpha, you don't have any slots left over for the color. Hence the restriction on having both in use at the same time.